# Python Selenium geckodriver print silently breaks printing

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver

I have searched and tried different things for days and I came up empty handed. The code is fairly straight forward.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
downloadfolder = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~/"),"mydownload")
os.chdir(downloadfolder)
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(downloadfolder)
profile.set_preference('print.always_print_silent',True)
profile.set_preference('print_printer','Print to File')
profile.set_preference('print.print_to_filename', 
    os.path.join(downloadfolder,'print.pdf'))
driver.webdriver.Firefox(profile)
driver.get("https://www.google.com") # or whatever site
driver.execute_script("window.print();")
```

This setup used to work, up to about a week ago, when I have noticed I am not getting the screen print.

When I try to print manually, I will get "An error occurred while printing".

What I have noticed in "about:config" on Firefox is that when I hit print, it will defaults to "PostScript/default". And no matter what I set it to, it will default to this value the moment I click on print.

Another thing that got me scratching my head. This does not happen if I don't set

```
profile.set_preference('print.always_print_silent',True)
```

But the dialog box shows. Any help appreciated.